# Factory and AbstractFactory in ZendFramework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-framework-mvc

What is the basic difference between Factory and Abstract Factory in ZF2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factory is used to create a single service per context. Abstract Factory is used to create many similar services per context. 
For instance, imagine that your application requires a single repository "UsersRepository" which connects to your database and allows you to fetch data from "Users" table. You would create a factory for this service as following:

```
class UsersRepositoryFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        return new \MyApp\Repository\UsersRepository();
    }
}
```

However, in real world, you may want to interact with many tables in your application, therefore you should consider to utilize Abstract Factory to create repository services for each table.

```
class RepositoryAbstractFactory implements AbstractFactoryInterface
{
    canCreateServiceWithName(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator, $name, $requestedName)
    {
        return class_exists('\MyApp\Repository\'.$requestedName);
    }

    createServiceWithName(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator, $name, $requestedName)
    {
        $class = '\MyApp\Repository\'.$requestedName;
        return new $class();
    }
}
```

As you can see, you don't have to create a separate factory for each repository service in your application.